# Codeigniter - redirect and download file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to force download after a submit (a .docx file generated with PhpWord), and redirect on another page in the same time.

here is the code generating the DOCX file:

```
$objWriter->save($filename);
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
header('Location: http://localhost/contracto_0.4/index.php/contrac)
readfile($filename);
unlink($filename); // deletes the temporary file
```

After this, I try to load a view, and I have this message from PHP:

```
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\wamp\www\contracto_0.5\system\core\Exceptions.php:185)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use download_helper:

```
    if ( ! function_exists('force_download'))
{
 function force_download($filename = '', $data = '')
 {
  if ($filename == '' OR $data == '')
  {
   return FALSE;
  }

  // Try to determine if the filename includes a file extension.
  // We need it in order to set the MIME type
  if (FALSE === strpos($filename, '.'))
  {
   return FALSE;
  }

  // Grab the file extension
  $x = explode('.', $filename);
  $extension = end($x);

  // Load the mime types
  @include(APPPATH.'config/mimes'.EXT);

  // Set a default mime if we can't find it
  if ( ! isset($mimes[$extension]))
  {
   $mime = 'application/octet-stream';
  }
  else
  {
   $mime = (is_array($mimes[$extension])) ? $mimes[$extension][0] : $mimes[$extension];
  }

  // Generate the server headers
  if (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "MSIE"))
  {
   header('Content-Type: "'.$mime.'"');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
   header('Expires: 0');
   header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
   header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
   header('Pragma: public');
   header("Content-Length: ".strlen($data));
  }
  else
  {
   header('Content-Type: "'.$mime.'"');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
   header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
   header('Expires: 0');
   header('Pragma: no-cache');
   header("Content-Length: ".strlen($data));
  }

  exit($data);
 }
}
```

and In your controller :

```
function donwload(){
$this->load->helper('download');
$data = file_get_contents('path/file.docx');
force_download('file.docx', $data);
}
```

above code available in [ellislab.com](https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/229903/#1041763)

Answer (score 0):

try use

```
redirect($filename);
```

if not work

in your codeignaiter index.php file add following locate in  root folder add  i solve
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by error and redirect it

```
ob_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the its because of this two lines of code you have, kindly change this two lines

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
```

TO

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
```

OR

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
```

Perhaps I don't have to explain to you line by line because its really easy to understand. Please refer to my old code below as a guide.. and actually it's still working on my live site.. feel free to test and modify it.

```
$error = '<p style="color:#990000">Sorry, the file you are requesting is unavailable.</p>';

if(isset($_GET['file']) && basename($_GET['file']) == $_GET['file'])
{
    $filename = $_GET['file'];
}
else
{
    $filename = null;
}

if($filename != null)
{
    $path = '../files/' . $filename;
    if (file_exists($path) && is_readable($path))
    {
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

        $file = @fopen($path, 'rb');
        if($file)
        {
            fpassthru($file);
            exit;
        }
        else
        {
            echo $error;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo $error;
    }
}
else
{
    echo $error;
}
```